# Wake on Lan через интернет

Tags: роутер, консоль

Дано:

1. Роутер ASUS RT-N13U
2. Компьютер, подключённый к нему, который надо разбудить с телефона
3. Доступ к настройкам роутера извне

Когда я с телефона вхожу в домашнюю сеть и отправляю широковещательную передачу на `192.168.1.255`, всё работает и компьютер включается. А вот при попытке разбудить компьютер извне я пoтерпел неудачу.

Пытался перенаправить все входящие соединения роутера напрямую на компьютер (`192.168.1.2`), но через пару минут после выключения компьютера роутер перестаёт отправлять пакет.

IP к компьютеру привязан на уровне DHCP на роутере, но, если я правильно понимаю, для успеха его надо привязать как-то сильнее к конкретному разъёму роутера или что-то подобное. Пробовал настроить перенаправление 9 порта извне на `192.168.1.255`, но роутер не воспринимает это перенаправление адекватно.

Помимо стандартных настроек роутера есть доступ к консоли. Набор возможностей там сильно ограничен, но всё же. Я вижу три стратегии решения проблемы, но не могу реализовать ни одну из них, в чём и прошу помощи:

1. Настроить как-то правильно широковещательное перенаправление
2. С помощью консоли привязать IP к компьютеру
3. Послать пакет напрямую из консоли роутера

Если у кого-то есть идеи как реализовать какой-либо из вариантов, буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть возможность включить компьютер извне, если внутри локалки есть устройство, которое пошлёт тот самый MAGIC PACKET, таким устройством может выступить сам роутер. На сколько я увидел, в родной прошивке ASUS RT-N13U такой функции нет, но можно установить прошивку dd-wrt (есть в http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database), openwrt или аналоги, подходящие под ваш роутер.

После прошивки появится возможность пользоваться Wake-On-LAN прямо с роутера через Интернет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы за NAT, то это невозможно. Пробросом портов, как вы уже пробовали, это не решается. Только через LAN. Отсюда совершенно сумасшедшая идея: пробросить VLAN до вашей локалки, и будить комп оттуда! Мысль чисто теоретическая, на практике ни разу не пробовал. Но вдруг сработает?